# How to insert into dynamodb table when multilple attributes are string variable in AWS lambda python environment?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, put

I am a newbie to the AWS lambda and DynamoDB world. I have a list of objects in the array, I want to insert these in each column on a partition key, how do I do it? My partition key is "s3url" and I want to dynamically set value true for all columns based on the values to read from the array:
example array: objects= ["cat", "person", "dog", "park"].

I need to create a column for each (if not exist) value in the above array and set value true in its respective row. Please note these attribute values are known in run time hence need to be passed as a variable. I have tried many ways but couldn't run it successfully.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest try going through the aws docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.WriteData.html).

Comment: Try converting the array into the object you want to insert, then insert using the putItem fn